# Spring Security 5 - My custom UserDetailsService is not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have found several questions about similar problems but none of them is exactly my case.

I am using the following class to configure the authentication/authorization in my application (a REST API).

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            )
            .antMatcher("/application-api/v1/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/application-api/v1/non-protected").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .opaqueToken();
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new ApplicationUserDetailsService();
    }
}
```

No matter what I try, my custom ApplicationUserDetailsService is never used.
Can anyone see what is wrong with this configuration?

I have also tried to specify the following bean:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationUserDetailsService.class);
    public ApplicationUserDetailsService() {
        logger.debug("Creating instance of ApplicationUserDetailsService");
    }
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) {
        logger.debug("Creating user details for {}", userName);

        return new ApplicationUser(userName);
    }
}
```

It did not work either.

**########### UPDATE ###########**

I have modified my SecurityConfiguration as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Qualifier("applicationUserDetailsService")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Oauth2 enabled: {}", enabled);
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            )
            .antMatcher("/application-api/v1/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/application-api/unprotected").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .opaqueToken();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
    }

    @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

I can see that my instance is used in the configuration, but nevertheless it is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the injection of the bean. Given that you are seeing the expected bean injected, the reason is probably that the service is not used.

You need to check what authentication provider you are using. With the default providers, the service is used only if you your authentication provider is based on username and password.

See for example the Spring documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html

The following article describes how to customise the user details.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-advanced-oauth2-user-service

Comment: I think that this can be the reason. How can I provide my custom user details ?

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but I will wait to see if others come up with the complete solution before assigning the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The cause probably is because you are constructing the `ApplicationUserDetailsService` using the new keyword that makes it non-spring dependency

you have 2 options either make the method return the `UserDetailsService` public with marking it with `@Bean`

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new ApplicationUserDetailsService();
}
```

OR

Inject `ApplicationUserDetailsService` in `SecurityConfiguration` via `@Autowired` or constructor injection
and in `configure` method set the security service in the `HttpSecurity` object

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);
    private ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService;
    // inject via constructor
    public SecurityConfig(ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService) {
        this.applicationUserDetailsService = applicationUserDetailsService;

    }    

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception 
    {
       httpSecurity.userDetailsService(applicationUserDetailsService);
       .... rest of security config code
    }
```

Comment: The bean is instantiated. I can see the log message. I have also verified that I can inject that bean in my SecurityConfiguration class (using @Autowired).
It seems to me that with the configuration that I am using  no UserDetails is ever called.
It's not only a problem with my custom UserDetails. It simply does not create the user details.
I can retrieve the userName using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() and so I am sure that the authentication is completed, but I do not see any UserDetails.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a case of bean creation order. It could be that at the time of creation of SecurityConfiguration the applicationUserDetailsService bean is not available to be Autowired. You can try to add `@dependson` on SecurityConfiguration and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned in my POST, my bean gets injected. The problem is that it is not used. I am sure that it gets injected because I've even tried to just manually instantiate it (you can see it in the code posted).

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting  UserDetailService inside your configuration. There is UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration which is by default from Spring.

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

Instead of userDetailsService, Autowire **ApplicationUserDetailsService** in SecurityConfiguration.
Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

//This should work. If not Found it will give error. Might be the case  where it is injecting Other UserDetailsService.
@Autowired
private ApplicationUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Oauth2 enabled: {}", enabled);
    httpSecurity.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling(e -> e
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        )
        .antMatcher("/application-api/v1/**").authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/application-api/unprotected").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .opaqueToken();
}

@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
}

@Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I wrote in other comments and in my POST , my bean gets injected. The problem is that it is not used. I am sure that it gets injected because I've even tried to just manually instantiate it (you can see it in the code posted).

Comment: You can also see in my code that I am using a qualifier and so it shouldn't be using the default bean.